# Python script to convert scripts to png files

Tags: python, python-3.x, image

I have written a Python script that converts scripts to png files, entirely by myself without anybody's help.

A picture is worth more than a thousand words so I will let the picture do the descriptions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

### ***Code***

```py
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters import ImageFormatter
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_by_name
from pygments.style import Style
from pygments.token import Name, Comment, String, Punctuation, Number, Operator, Literal, Keyword


class MyStyle(Style):
    styles = {
        Keyword: 'bold #07487f bg:#00122a',
        Name: '#7b68ee bg:#00122a',
        Name.Builtin: 'italic #fb4570',
        Name.Class: 'bold italic #ffd700',
        Name.Constant: 'bold',
        Name.Decorator: 'bold italic',
        Name.Exception: 'bold italic #ff005d',
        Name.Function: 'bold italic #134dbc',
        Name.Namespace: 'bold italic #ffa000',
        Name.Variable.Class: 'bold',
        Name.Variable.Global: 'bold',
        Literal: '#00ff80 bg:#00122a',
        String: '#20ff40 bg:#00122a',
        String.Escape: 'italic #d06000',
        Number: '#00c0ff bg:#00122a',
        Operator: 'bold #408020 bg:#00122a',
        Operator.Word: 'bold #0000f0',
        Punctuation: '#ff00c0 bg:#00122a',
        Comment: 'italic #800080 bg:#00122a'
    }


def script2png(filepath, language='python'):
    code = '\n'.join([i.rstrip() for i in Path(
        filepath).read_text(encoding='utf8').splitlines()])
    formatter = ImageFormatter(style=MyStyle, full=True,
        font_name='Source Code Pro', font_size=16,
        line_number_bg='#003b6f', line_number_fg='#ff69b4',
        line_number_bold=True, line_pad=3)
    image = highlight(code, get_lexer_by_name(language), formatter)
    image = np.array(Image.open(BytesIO(image)))
    image[np.all(image == (255, 255, 255), axis=-1)] = (0, 18, 42)
    image = Image.fromarray(image)
    image.save(filepath+'.png')
```

How is the code? This is my first time writing something like this, and I really want to know how to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing a lot of symbols from `pygments.token`. It is probably cleaner to alias that import and clean up your namespace a bit.

I don't see why you're jumping through so many hoops when splitting and joining your text. Why not just read the entire file as a string and leave it be?

`pygments` is poorly designed. It has a lot of internal inconsistencies, such as some `Style` members being respected for some formatter subclasses and not others. You should be moving as much styling information to your style class as possible. `pygments` has a deeply confused interpretation of `line_number_bg`: it can (and often is) expressed as `Style.line_number_background_color`, but the latter is only respected in CSS mode. Still: better to define it on your class, and manually pass it in for the `ImageFormatter` constructor that is broken and does not respect the style.

Do not use Numpy or Pillow and do not replace your background by colour. Instead, define `Style.background_color`.

Both your `BytesIO` and your `Image` should be put in a `with` for guaranteed closure.

Unless you need to do something strange and non-standard, it is more convenient to remove your `language` argument and replace `get_lexer_by_name` with `get_lexer_for_filename`.

If you absolutely require a `.png` you should be passing that format explicitly to the formatter. Otherwise, a reasonable implementation would be a `script2img` that allows the `ImageFormatter` to use its default format, whatever that may be; does not hard-code the `.png` suffix; and instead pulls that from `formatter.image_format`.

### Suggested

```py
from pathlib import Path
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters import ImageFormatter
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_for_filename
from pygments.style import Style
import pygments.token as tokens


class MyStyle(Style):
    background_color = '#00122a'

    # Only applies to HtmlFormatter
    line_number_background_color = '#003b6f'
    line_number_color = '#ff69b4'

    styles = {
        tokens.Keyword: f'bold #07487f bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.Name: f'#7b68ee bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.Name.Builtin: 'italic #fb4570',
        tokens.Name.Class: 'bold italic #ffd700',
        tokens.Name.Constant: 'bold',
        tokens.Name.Decorator: 'bold italic',
        tokens.Name.Exception: 'bold italic #ff005d',
        tokens.Name.Function: 'bold italic #134dbc',
        tokens.Name.Namespace: 'bold italic #ffa000',
        tokens.Name.Variable.Class: 'bold',
        tokens.Name.Variable.Global: 'bold',
        tokens.Literal: f'#00ff80 bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.String: f'#20ff40 bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.String.Escape: 'italic #d06000',
        tokens.Number: f'#00c0ff bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.Operator: f'bold #408020 bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.Operator.Word: 'bold #0000f0',
        tokens.Punctuation: f'#ff00c0 bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.Comment: f'italic #800080 bg:{background_color}',
    }


def script2img(filepath: Path) -> None:
    formatter = ImageFormatter(
        style=MyStyle, full=True, line_pad=3,
        font_name='Source Code Pro', font_size=16,
        line_number_bold=True,
        line_number_fg=MyStyle.line_number_color,
        line_number_bg=MyStyle.line_number_background_color,
    )
    buffer = highlight(
        code=filepath.read_text(),
        lexer=get_lexer_for_filename(filepath),
        formatter=formatter,
    )
    with filepath.with_suffix(
        '.' + formatter.image_format
    ).open('wb') as f:
        f.write(buffer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    script2img(Path('275768.py'))
```

### Output

Rendering its own source,

[image: rendered python source]

This works equally well (still without passing a `language`) when inferring Java:

[image: rendered java source]

### Caching configuration

If you're rendering multiple files at a time, you may want to make a class version that caches the instantiated formatter:

```
from pathlib import Path
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.formatters import ImageFormatter
from pygments.lexers import get_lexer_for_filename
from pygments.style import Style
import pygments.token as tokens


class MyStyle(Style):
    background_color = '#00122a'

    # Only applies to HtmlFormatter
    line_number_background_color = '#003b6f'
    line_number_color = '#ff69b4'

    styles = {
        tokens.Keyword: f'bold #07487f bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.Name: f'#7b68ee bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.Name.Builtin: 'italic #fb4570',
        tokens.Name.Class: 'bold italic #ffd700',
        tokens.Name.Constant: 'bold',
        tokens.Name.Decorator: 'bold italic',
        tokens.Name.Exception: 'bold italic #ff005d',
        tokens.Name.Function: 'bold italic #134dbc',
        tokens.Name.Namespace: 'bold italic #ffa000',
        tokens.Name.Variable.Class: 'bold',
        tokens.Name.Variable.Global: 'bold',
        tokens.Literal: f'#00ff80 bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.String: f'#20ff40 bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.String.Escape: 'italic #d06000',
        tokens.Number: f'#00c0ff bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.Operator: f'bold #408020 bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.Operator.Word: 'bold #0000f0',
        tokens.Punctuation: f'#ff00c0 bg:{background_color}',
        tokens.Comment: f'italic #800080 bg:{background_color}',
    }


class Highlighter:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.formatter = ImageFormatter(
            style=MyStyle, full=True, line_pad=3,
            font_name='Source Code Pro', font_size=16,
            line_number_bold=True,
            line_number_fg=MyStyle.line_number_color,
            line_number_bg=MyStyle.line_number_background_color,
        )
        self.extension = '.' + self.formatter.image_format

    def script_to_image(self, filepath: Path) -> Path:
        buffer = highlight(
            code=filepath.read_text(),
            lexer=get_lexer_for_filename(filepath),
            formatter=self.formatter,
        )

        out_path = filepath.with_suffix(self.extension)
        with out_path.open('wb') as f:
            f.write(buffer)
        return out_path


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Highlighter().script_to_image(Path('275768.py'))
```

Comment: Good answer, but I can't accept it just yet. You know, gotta wait for 24 hours so people around the globe can have a chance to see the question and post an answer.

Comment: About splitting and joining the text, it is to remove trailing white spaces, I sometimes write code on Windows Terminal to see what the output will be, and I then copy pasted the code to Visual Studio Code,  I used Alt+Drag to select the code, and this will leave trailing spaces, I guess they will make the output sub-optimal so I want to remove them.

Comment: The only effect will be a broadened right margin. I consider that harmless, but if you really care about it, you could follow your original approach or do something like a `re.sub(r' *\n', '\n'`.